# Create SQLite DB with multiple tables in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

In my development of an ipad applicacion, I need a database with 5 tables, but, I don't know why in my code, only execute 1 statement and don't return any error:

```
            const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CATEGORIAS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE TEXT)";

            char *error;

            if(sqlite3_exec(dieneDB, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK){

                **sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST SUBCATEGORIAS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_CATEGORIA INTEGER, NOMBRE TEXT)";**

                if(sqlite3_exec(dieneDB, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK){

                    sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST FORMATOS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE TEXT)";

                    if(sqlite3_exec(dieneDB, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK){

                        sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST BEBIDAS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_CATEGORIA INTEGER, ID_SUBCATEGORIA INTEGER, NOMBRE TEXT, DESCRIPCION TEXT, RUTA_IMAGEN TEXT)";

                        if(sqlite3_exec(dieneDB, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK){

                            sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST BEBIDASFORMATOS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_BEBIDA INTEGER, ID_FORMATO INTEGER)";

                            if(sqlite3_exec(dieneDB, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK){

                                NSLog(@"All tables are created");

                                sqlite3_close(dieneDB);

                                [self loadData];

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }else{

                NSLog(@"Unable to create some table %s", error);

            }

        }else{

            NSLog(@"Database Exists Already");

            [self clearData]   
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error opening database");   
    }
}
```

It crash in the second sqlStatement and go to the}else{

```
                NSLog(@"Unable to create some table %s", error);
```

But not log anythink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your SQL would appear to be that your first SQL statement correctly uses `IF NOT EXISTS`, but the rest use `IF NOT EXIST`.

You're probably not seeing your error message because you're only logging errors if the first `sqlite3_exec` fails. The rest of the `if` statements don't have `else` clauses. You probably want to `NSLog` the `error` for each failed `sqlite3_exec` call.

---

Alternatively, `sqlite3_exec`, unlike other SQLite functions, accepts multiple SQL statements, terminated with semicolons. Thus greatly simplifying your code since with only one `sqlite3_exec`, you only need one `else` statement:

```
const char *sqlStatement =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CATEGORIAS      (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE TEXT);"
                            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SUBCATEGORIAS   (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_CATEGORIA INTEGER, NOMBRE TEXT);"
                            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FORMATOS        (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE TEXT);"
                            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BEBIDAS         (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_CATEGORIA INTEGER, ID_SUBCATEGORIA INTEGER, NOMBRE TEXT, DESCRIPCION TEXT, RUTA_IMAGEN TEXT);"
                            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BEBIDASFORMATOS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_BEBIDA INTEGER, ID_FORMATO INTEGER);";

char *error;

if(sqlite3_exec(dieneDB, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"All tables are created");
    [self loadData];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to create some table %s", error);
    sqlite3_free(error);
    error = NULL;
}
```

Note, I've fixed the `IF NOT EXISTS` error, above. Also, note, if you get an error message, you're responsible for freeing it with `sqlite3_free`.

Comment: This makes me feel a newbie. I'm sorry to have wasted your time to all who have read my message ... Thanks!!!

Comment: @PlugInBoy No worries. BTW, I've updated my answer with a code sample that would not only log the error correctly, but greatly simplifies your code.